# Inexpensive firebase listeners

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am curious to know what is the internal implementation of firebase listeners like?

I have heard firebase engineers saying firebase listeners are inexpensive to use and can be used as much required. While I agree that they make the app real time. What happens if I have a bunch of firebase listeners in my app(a real time chess playing application for multiple users.)

The listeners are listening to bunch of actions including when a move is made by a player in a game or when a new game is started. Easy to imagine the scale if I have hundreds of thousands of users using the application concurrently everyday.

How does firebase handle so many requests on their server since they have given the power of listeners to the end user.

We can have as many listeners as we want in our firebase app. How is this inexpensive?

Please correct me if I am wrong in my inherent assumptions.

Answer (score 6):

Firebase uses WebSockets, which is a persistent connection to the server. This means that you don't have to worry about making a request, because the only HTTP request that gets made is in the very beginning to establish the socket. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Client_Handshake_Request) is more information about Web sockets which is a different protocol from HTTP. So in your case it's completely feasible to make many separate "requests" for the data, because there's no real overhead to consider. The device's radio is already on, and a WebSocket header is merely 6 bytes.

Comment: I think the question rather is about how the server knows which data to send to each client (at least that's the answer my curiosity is looking for). I can't imagine an implementation of this which is inexpensive (in terms of speed and memory).